# Inequality $\sqrt{a_1a_2}+\sqrt{a_2a_3}+\cdots+ \sqrt{a_{n-1}a_n}≤ \frac{n-1}{2}(a_1+a_2+ \cdots + a_n)$

Tags: inequality

If $a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n$ are positive numbers, prove following inequality:

$\sqrt{a_1a_2}+\sqrt{a_2a_3}+ \cdots + \sqrt{a_{n-1}a_n}≤ \frac{n-1}{2}(a_1+a_2+ \cdots + a_n)$

I know the solution, though there may be other algorithms. I will post my solution if there is no identical one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the inequality $\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\sqrt{a_ia_j}<\frac{n-1}2\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458204/prove-the-inequality-sum-1-le-ij-le-n-sqrta-ia-j-fracn-12-sum-i-1n)

Answer (score 4):

I assume the left hand side should be

$$\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \sqrt{a_ia_j}$$

and not

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}\sqrt{a_ia_{i+1}}$$

since that would be strange and follows from the one I'm gonna show. So I'm gonna prove the following:

$$\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \sqrt{a_ia_j} \leq \frac{n-1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^na_i$$

This is simple enough since it follows from the AM-GM inequality:

$$\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \sqrt{a_ia_j} \leq \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}\frac{1}{2}(a_i+a_j)=\frac{n-1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^na_i$$

Answer (score 3):

Arithmetic-Geometric mean inequality says that:

$$\sqrt{a_i a_j} \leq (a_i + a_j)/2 $$

Do this for $(i,j) = (1,2), \dots, (n, n-1)$ and add them all up.

$$ \sqrt{a_1 a_2} + \sqrt{a_2 a_3} + \dots + \sqrt{a_{n-1} a_n} \leq \frac{a_1}{2} + a_2 + ... + a_{n-1} + \frac{a_{n}}{2}$$

For $n > 1$, the result follows.

**Edit:**

I Agree with Atticus's answer in that you probably have a typo in the question, for which when fixed as a far tighter inequality.